# Spam, even with captcha on Php Form

Tags: php, spam-prevention

I have a funny problem and i have no idea how to fix it. I have a contact form on my website that also writes the details to a db. The form is getting allot of spam. I put a captcha on it but it is not stopping the spam coming through.

The code that actually send the email and writes to the db is not actually held in the file with the captcha but in a helper file that gets the data posted to it, Is it possible that the spam is hitting this file directly and not the Actual form?

Its funny beacuse I have another contact form without a captcha on the same site that gets no spam at all?

Any help be really appreciated,

Thanks

Comment: I'd like to see the website

Comment: Most likely (if its automated spam), they will readout the form's action attribute and post to that page directly. So if your Captcha check is NOT validated inside your helper-file (you mentioned) its useless.

Answer (score 3):

1) It may be that your CAPTCHA is weak and just automatically cracked by the spam robot

2) Is the CAPTCHA validation in the server side handling class? If it is not, it is pretty useless because anybody can just post to the form.

Comment: I found a plugin for a BB I admin which randomises the "real" post data names to prevent spam and ignores the "expected" ones, it's simple but has been amazingly effective.

Answer (score 3):

Doesn't the code that send email and writes to db checks if captcha is correct or not?
if not you need to modify the code else purpose of captcha is not met....

if yes there is possibility that the captcha is very poor, and their spamming bots are able to recognize captch.

you can alternatively store IP address of messages being sent to you in db and bann IPs of spammers as they tend to be using certain IPs

Thanks

Comment: Thanks for reply. No i just have it so the form wont submit if the captcha is wrong..

Comment: you dont check the captcha on server side?